# How to compare date time string to the current time in python

Tags: python

I have this string `Thu 15 Sep 2022 11:43:49 PM UTC`  and I want the difference in seconds between it and the current time.

How do I accomplish this in python?

Answer (score 1):

You would use the `datetime.strptime` function from the `datetime` module (don't be confused, you import `datetime` from `datetime` and then call `datetime.strptime`--I know). You'd apply to that the correct date-string formatting.

Here's a [good overview](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-datetime-strptime-function/) of the different formatting elements you can use with `strptime`.

I've made a few assumptions about zero-padding numbers (e.g., would 1 p.m. be 01:00 or 1:00?), but with that in mind, the following should work:

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime_str = "Thu 15 Sep 2022 11:43:49 PM UTC"
fmt = r"%a %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %p %Z"
parsed_datetime = datetime.strptime(datetime_str, fmt)
seconds_diff = (parsed_datetime - datetime.now()).seconds
```

Comment: Please don't answer duplicate questions. In such situations, the recommended action is to flag / vote to close as a duplicate.

Comment: There's one issue: This is returning 3:00 when it should be 15:00 (miliary time). It's like that part is missed.

Comment: You can adjust 12 v. 24 hour clock. `%I` is 12-hour, `%H` is 24-hour.